# what are the differences beetween notifyUrl response and completePurchase response?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox, omnipay

i'm try to use omnipay/paypal, i use this code for returnUrl page:

```
public function completePayment(Request $request)
{

    //return 'pagina dopo acquisto';
    $gateway = Omnipay::create('PayPal_Express');
    $gateway->setUsername('blastor_89-facilitator_api1.msn.com');
    $gateway->setPassword('BEWB2BEW9CHCV3EQ');
    $gateway->setSignature('AFcWxV21C7fd0v3bYYYRCpSSRl31AC5Dp4AnVYBnMIkNFxSQTj8h.lqD');
    $gateway->setTestMode(true);

    $params = session()->get('params');
    $response = $gateway->completePurchase($params)->send();
    $paypalResponse = $response->getData();
    //$this->store($paypalResponse);
    if(isset($paypalResponse['PAYMENTINFO_0_ACK']) && $paypalResponse['PAYMENTINFO_0_ACK'] === 'Success') {
        // here you process the response. Save to database ...

    }
    else {
        // Failed transaction ...
    }
}
```

it response with $paypalResponse, while if i use notifyUrl page what do notifyUrl response? what are the differences?

Answer (score 0):

These two responses are completely different although they contain the same basic idea.

The complete purchase response has the data from your call to completePurchase().  The notify response has data that is fed into your application from a notify (PayPal IPN) call.  I suggest that you dump the data from each one to take a look.